# How to ORDER BY DateTime in Doctrine but first show data without dates

Tags: sql, symfony, zend-framework, doctrine

I have a question and I hope you can help me with it.
I want to show all activities from the database order by date but first I have to show the activities without dates! I don't know how to solve this problem with Doctrine.

For example:

```
1. Activity01
2. Activity02
3. Activity03 2020-07-23
4. Activity04 2020-07-25
5. Activity05 2020-07-28
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `case` expressions. Here is the [demo](https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/4wHC1RVbknBYRWUhVsioq8/0) to check.

```
select
    *
from yourTable
order by
    case 
        when dateCol is null then 1
        else 2
    end
```

Comment: Thank u for ur fast answer :-)